Did I pass wind or is it shaytan?
I apologise for the details. Often when I’m in Salah I become very gassy and break my wushu without doubt. But sometimes I simply feel a hit sensation between my buttocks and then the need to pass wind disappears. I’m very conflicted wether I actually broke my wushu those times or not… is there a way to be sure about it?
